# Problems copying data to another Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with data and I want to copy the values from that sheet to the main sheet.

The data from the Import sheet is obtained by several arrayformulas, so when I copy it to the main sheet, it doesn't copy properly.

How can I copy only the final result of that sheet? (the "visible" part only)

```
function copyTo() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
      sheet = source.getSheetByName('ImportJSON'),
      destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      destSheet = destination.getSheetByName('universe'),
      copydSheet = sheet.copyTo(destination);
  copydSheet.getDataRange().copyTo(destSheet.getDataRange(),{contentsOnly:true});
  destination.deleteSheet(copydSheet);
}
```

[image: Original Sheet]

[image: Result after copy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the script below:

```js
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SOURCE'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('SOURCE_SHEET'); // ss = source sheet
  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('TARGET'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('TARGET_SHEET'); // ts = target sheet
  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

}
```

Just substitute `SOURCE`, `SOURCE_SHEET`, `TARGET`, and `TARGET_SHEET` to what fits your needs.

Comment: There is an error, "TypeError: copydSheet.getDataRange(...).getValues(...).copyTo is not a function". Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have edited my answer, it should hopefully work now.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Maybe it's because I'm copying a sheet and not a range.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I could help.